# Calling SQL Scrips from a sql script!

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am just wondering if it is possible to call multiple SQL scripts from a single startup.sql script.

i.e.

StartUp.sql calls:

CreateDatabase.sql
CreateStoreProcedureFirst.sql
CreateStoreProcedureSecond.sql
InsertDummyValues.sql
otherscripts.sql... etc

At the moment I am loading and running each file one at a time.. there are more scripts I run also and sometimes miss a script or do it in the wrong order!

Hope this meakes sense

Thanks

Comment: Forgot to add that I am using SQL Server Management Studio Express to create and run the scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - you can use SQLCMD (SQL Server 2005 or later) to make T-SQL scripts a little more flexible, with the equivalent of includes and basic variables.

The SQLCMD command for include is **:r** as in:

```
:r c:\someFolder\script1.sql
:r c:\someFolder\script2.sql
```

etc.

See http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1543

Answer (score 1):

Number them and use a tool like http://code.google.com/p/simplescriptrunner/ or http://code.google.com/p/tarantino/

Answer (score 0):

Both Oracle and MySQL have command line tools and from experience i know you can run them thus

```
mysql database_name < yoursql.sql > output.tab
```

however this means running from the CLI not from an original SQL statement so may not be what you are looking for. I don't believe you can make calls to the system from MySQL

Answer (score 0):

mcintyre321's links look handy...

I used powershell to do something similar.  I'd name all of my setup scripts with a prefix and a 1.x in whatever order they needed to be compiled.

I then named all my teardown scripts 3.x in the proper order.

The command in cmd window:

```
PS builddir:\> .\buildsql.ps1 -currentbuilddir "C:\Documents and Settings\SGreene\My Documents\svn\Ticketing" -buildfile "sqlbuild.sql" -teardownfile
"teardown.sql"
```

The powershell script (buildsql.ps1)

```
param($currentbuilddir,$buildfile1,$teardownfile)

new-psdrive -name builddir -PSProvider filesystem -Root (resolve-path $currentbuilddir)

cd builddir:

rm $buildfile1
rm $teardownfile


Get-item COM_ENCRYPT_1* | ForEAch-object {cat $_ >> $buildfile1; "GO --SYSTEM INSERTED GO--------------" >> $buildfile1} 

Get-item COM_ENCRYPT_3* | ForEAch-object {cat $_ >> $teardownfile; "GO --SYSTEM INSERTED GO------------" >> $teardownfile}
```

My first time doing this, but it seemed to work OK.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used or heard of dynamic sql?  This is how i would do it...

DECLARE @SQL1PROCEDURE nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @SQL2PROCEDURE nvarchar(4000)

SET @SQL1Procedure = 
     ' CREATE PROC sp1
           AS
             BEGIN
             blah blah blah
             END
     '

SET @SQL2Procedure = 
     ' INSERT DUMMY TABLE (FIELD1,FIELD2) VALUES (VALUE 1,VALUE2)'

EXEC @SQL1Procedure
EXEC @SQL2Procedure